# Github->AWS CodeDeploy when changing certain files

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I've tried to configure auto deployment from github to aws codedeploy. I found some useful tutorials (like https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy) and it works.

I have two problems:
1. I would like to trigger AWS CodeDeploy only if I add/change files in root folder and not in subfolders (or in certain subfolder). 
Reason: I use my repo to store ML tasks, each ML model is stored in a separate script in root (or in 'models' ). When I update other files, I don't want to start deployment.
2. I would like to start 1 AWS instance for each changed model, i.e. for each file in root folder (or model subfolder).

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be looking at using more than just Github and CodeDeploy. Specifically you need a Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery system.  Examples:

- Atlasssian Bamboo
- CircleCI
- Jenkins
- TravisCI

You'll be able to configure things a bit more in one of these tools. And they usually allow some lightweight scripting.